# XML Parser Reading Channel Description Tags

Tags: xml, swift, rss

I have a xml parser that parses the feed of sharontalon.com/feed
However, when the strings are put into the table, the description of the feed is used as the first item description, bumping all the post descriptions down an item. How can I skip the first description tag?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kYVT.png

This is the XMLParser

```html
  import UIKit



@objc protocol XMLParserDelegate{

func parsingWasFinished()

}



class XMLParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

   

var arrParsedData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()



var currentDataDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()



var currentElement = ""



var foundCharacters = ""



var delegate : XMLParserDelegate?





func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: NSURL) {

    let parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)

    parser!.delegate = self

    parser!.parse()

}











func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {

    delegate?.parsingWasFinished()

}





func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    

    currentElement = elementName

}





func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {

    if !foundCharacters.isEmpty {

        

        if elementName == "link" || elementName == "description"{

            foundCharacters = (foundCharacters as NSString).substringFromIndex(3)

        }

        

        

        currentDataDictionary[currentElement] = foundCharacters

        

        foundCharacters = ""

        

        if currentElement == "pubDate" {

            arrParsedData.append(currentDataDictionary)

        }

        

    }

}





func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String!) {

    if (currentElement == "title" ) || currentElement == "description" || currentElement == "link" || currentElement == "pubDate"{

        foundCharacters += string

    }

}





func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError!) {

    print(parseError.description)

}





func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, validationErrorOccurred validationError: NSError!) {

    print(validationError.description)

}



}
```

This is the TableView Controller

```html
import UIKit



class TopicsTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {



    var xmlParser : XMLParser!

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://sharontalon.com/feed")

        xmlParser = XMLParser()

        xmlParser.delegate = self

        xmlParser.startParsingWithContentsOfURL(url!)

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }



    

    // MARK: XMLParserDelegate method implementation

    

    func parsingWasFinished() {

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    

    

  



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return xmlParser.arrParsedData.count

    }



    

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        

        let currentDictionary = xmlParser.arrParsedData[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, String>

        

        cell.textLabel?.text = currentDictionary["title"]

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = currentDictionary["description"]

        return cell

    }

    

    

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 80

    }

    

    

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let dictionary = xmlParser.arrParsedData[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, String>

        let tutorialLink = dictionary["link"]

        let publishDate = dictionary["pubDate"]

        

        let tutorialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idTutorialViewController") as! TutorialViewController

        

        tutorialViewController.tutorialURL = NSURL(string: tutorialLink!)

        tutorialViewController.publishDate = publishDate

        

        showDetailViewController(tutorialViewController, sender: self)

        

    }

    


}
```

Thanks for Any Help

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. I tried your code, [and this is the result](http://s30.postimg.org/3zxfwiddd/Screen_Shot_2015_10_25_at_01_06_36.png) so what is your problem again please ?

Comment: I see the problem now, there is one shift always between the title and the description. let me try to help

Comment: I wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because in your XML data, there is a `description` tag inside the `cannel` tag and your are inserting the data to `arrParsedData` dictionary when reaching the `pubDate` tag and which comes **BEFORE** the next `description` tag, you were unlucky because the `channel` tag already contained the `description` tag so you didn't feel the error. but if it didn't, an exception would have happened telling you that there is no tag called `description`. I changed your condition

```
 if currentElement == "pubDate"
```

to :

```
if currentElement == "description" && !isFirst
```

I added the `isFirst` variable to avoid the first `description` tag that is under the `channel` tag. Kindly also see the `else` part that i have added

```
if currentElement == "description" && !isFirst

        {
            arrParsedData.append(currentDataDictionary)   
        }else {
            if currentElement == "description" && isFirst {
                isFirst = false
            }
        }
```

This is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

And this is the new  `XMLParserDelegate` . I also corrected some of the signature of the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods

```
 import UIKit

 @objc protocol XMLParserDelegate{

    func parsingWasFinished()

 }

 class XMLParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    var arrParsedData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
    var currentDataDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
    var currentElement = ""
    var foundCharacters = ""
    var delegate : XMLParserDelegate?
    var isFirst = true
    func startParsingWithContentsOfURL(rssURL: NSURL) {

        let parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: rssURL)

        parser!.delegate = self

        parser!.parse()

    }


    func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {

        delegate?.parsingWasFinished()

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        currentElement = elementName
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {


            if !foundCharacters.isEmpty {
                if elementName == "link" || elementName == "description" {
                    foundCharacters = (foundCharacters as NSString).substringFromIndex(3)
                }
                currentDataDictionary[currentElement] = foundCharacters

                foundCharacters = ""

                if currentElement == "description" && !isFirst

                {
                    arrParsedData.append(currentDataDictionary)
                }else {
                    if currentElement == "description" && isFirst {
                        isFirst = false
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

        if currentElement == "title"  || currentElement == "description"
            || currentElement == "link" || currentElement == "pubDate"
        {

            foundCharacters += string

        }

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {

        print(parseError.description)

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, validationErrorOccurred validationError: NSError) {

        print(validationError.description)

    }

 }
```